# href="../" links to root instead of parent directory

Tags: html, directory, href

I'm writing a simple web server and doing some directory traversals, and in each directory I include a link to the parent directory for going back up.

However, regardless of my depth in the directory tree, when I create that parent link (using href="../" in my link), it goes right back to the root.

For example:
   - I am in localhost:2345/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
   - HTML page displays links to files & directories in dir4, including parent
   - "parent" is linked (<\a>) with (href="../")
   - Click "parent" --> directed to localhost:2345/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a couple of things I would try to do: 
(1) Check web server redirection settings
(2) Does the web server require file extension (ex. .html .htm) to properly load the page? You can probably try **../index.html** if the root file of the parent directory is named **index.html**.

Comment: I think it's because I just pass it as "../" as though it's a regular directory command, and it's being interpreted as (root)/../.  

The reason I was trying it this way is that appending the "../" to the current location was resulting in duplicate directories in the path.

Comment: Before, I was appending the "../" to the current directory path, but as a result, when I returned to the parent directory, I had duplicate intermediate file names. For example:   
  
http://localhost:2345/Dir0/Dir0/dir0_file1.txt